# printf gives a question mark when trying to locate a hex mem location

Tags: linux, assembly, hex, printf

I have tried to print out a hex memory location on linux (linux mint, kali linux, and ubunutu) using the following command :

```
printf "\xaa" 
?
```

and all I get as an output is a question mark which means as I understand that the hex memory is not recognized ?

Comment: What is your locale settings and how is your terminal's encoding configured?

Comment: unidecode(utf-8)

Comment: please provide a link to the paper describing this vulnerability.

Comment: it's a simple c code : char buffer[8] with 8 words and i am using the gets fucntion and providing more than 8 word => smashing the stack.

Comment: You have to pipe the `printf` shell command's output into the program you're attacking, otherwise it just prints the output on the terminal.  There's no memory or asm involved in anything you posted in this question, just a `bash` command.

Answer (score 1):

`printf "\xaa"` prints the character that corresponds to the hex code "aa" (170 in decimal), it has nothing to do with memory locations.

What you see depends on the encoding settings of your terminal. If your terminal is configured to display UTF-8, you probably see the question mark in a diamond:

```
�
```

It means the byte sequence `aa` doesn't correspond to any UTF-8 character.

You can also use a hexdump tool (e.g. `xxd`) to display the hex representation of the output:

```
$ printf '\xaa' | xxd
0000000: aa                                       .
```

For example, the sequence `c2 a1` encodes `LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH ACUTE`:

```
$ printf '\xc3\xa1\n'
á
```

Comment: the thing is that i'm trying to exploit a buffer overflow in my own created code and while executing the payload it gives the same thing, that's why i am trying to see the output of \xaa abd it should gives a balnk space or nothing as an output and not a question mark, when could i configure my terminal  ?

Comment: It depends on what terminal you're using.

Comment: i am on linux mint and using Gnome terminal 3.18.3 configured on Unicode(UTF-8) what do you suggest as a config ?

Comment: I still don't understand what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: trying to exploit a buffer overflow vulnerability by loading a real memory location from the stack

Comment: `printf "\xaa"` doesn't load a real memory location.

Comment: @user3717888 when you type man printf (on the same command line)  do you see anything like this in there?        \xHH   byte with hexadecimal value HH (1 to 2 digits)

Comment: @old_timer yes i do see it  (\xaa) is just to test if hex are working with printf)